# Unable to set Tab Bar Badge value on Refactored Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, tabbar

I refactored my storyboard and now I'm unable to set the badge value on the refactored storyboard.

This is the main story board and MessageCenter is the refactored storyboard.

[image]

Message Center StoryBoard:

[image]

I'm setting the badge value in the app delegate, which isn't working:

if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.tabBar.items![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fM4.png).badgeValue = "3"
}

Any ideas?

Comment: there is only one element in the refactored tab bar controller....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code in your TabBarCustomViewController:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = "3"
})
```

Comment: Probably you're not on the main thread, if you want to change something related with the UI you need to be in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
tabBarController.viewControllers?[2].tabBarItem.badgeValue = "3"
}

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt work.  Thanks though.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, I swear it worked on my machine :)